# when condition isn't satisfied, must go back to input

Tags: c++

I want to be able to input a number between 1 and 100 and then print the according value to my txt file. If the number is less than 1 or bigger than 100 i should go back to input and try again till i finally meet the condition. This is what i have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c, e = 100;
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("num_gen.txt");
    while (0)
    {
        cout << "Enter starting value from 1 to 100: " << endl;
        cin >> c;
        if (c <= 0)
            cout << "Value is too small" << endl;
        else if (c >= 100)
            cout << "Value is too big" << endl;
        else
        {
            //while (c > 0 && c < 100)
            //{
            for (c; c <= e; c++)
            {
                outputFile << "<" << c << c << c << c << endl;
            }
            //}
        }
    }
        cout << "Press enter to exit...";
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing in this? And why `while(0)`? It will immediately exit the loop!

Comment: `while(0)`? ...

Comment: i was trying while(1) as well, but that didnt work either

Comment: Because you didn't use `break`.

Comment: You have to break out of the loop! Use something like this: `if(c <= 0) { cout<<"Value is too small!\n"; break; }`

Comment: @LogicStuff, it was an example. He can use it at a more appropriate place! ;-)

Comment: I'd hoist the logic of writing the output file out of the loop.  After all, you want to keep looping until input is valid.  After that, do the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int c, e = 100;
  ofstream outputFile;
  outputFile.open("num_gen.txt");
  while (true)
    {
      cout << "Enter starting value from 1 to 100: " << endl;
      cin >> c;
      if (c <= 0)
        cout << "Value is too small" << endl;
      else if (c >= 100)
        cout << "Value is too big" << endl;
      else
        {
          while (c > 0 && c < 100)
            {
              outputFile << "<" << c << c << c << c << endl;
              c++;
            }
          break;
        }
    }

  cout << "Press enter to exit..." << endl;
  cin.get();
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is great, but it only works if i have to print "<" and one number. For example <34. What i want to do is, i want to print that number 4 times and then on to the next number. It should look like this <34343434, <35353535... adding more c++'s doesnt really work that way.

Comment: Then split outputFile << "<" << c++ << endl; into two lines. Put the c++ on a separate line

Comment: i did this,  outputFile << "<" << c++; outputFile << c << c << c << endl; but it prints <34353535, 35363636, 36373737...

Comment: works like it should now. does that break; also breaks the first while(true) loop ?

Comment: @user3446665 it breaks the loop that it is most closely scoped within. so yes

Comment: shouldnt the break be inside the while(true) loop? at the end of it. or maybe it doesnt matter and it breaks anyways?

Comment: @user3446665 it is within the while(true) loop. just at a different scope level. Try something like the following and you will see what happens when you try to use a break without a valid corresponding enclosing statement (in this case while(true)). try to COMPILE:  " int main() { while(true); break; } "

Comment: if i use break; just before closing the while(true) loop then its not allowing me to enter a value again if it was too small or too big. so i guess the break is in the right place. im not sure tho which statement does it break exactly. does it break the else statement or does it break while (c > 0 && c < 100)?

Comment: @user3446665 it breaks of out the closest **enclosing** (scope wise) loop.

Comment: it means that first it breaks the else statement when the conditions are not met anymore and then breaks while(true). am i right?

Comment: @user3446665 'else' is not a loop so it doesn't need to 'break' out of it (and in fact cannot). The first breakable statement is the enclosing 'while(true)' statement